# Boot error: No boot detected or disk has failed

Tags: boot

possible duplicate but earlier questions did not solve my issue.
I installed Ubuntu 13.04 in my ACER desktop. Initially it was not able to start Ubuntu on normal start up as priority was not set in BIOS. So, I set priority in BIOS but still I am getting above error during boot up. What could possibly happen? Disk error/installation problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the disk is in failure stages according to the message.

Start your PC and go into the BIOS and see if there is a hard disk diagnostic test and run it.  Also you may see the hard drive manufacturer website, and see if they have a testing utility.

It also may have to do with the BIOS.  Check with Acer, and see if they have a BIOS update.

Comment: I checked disk for errors using badblocks. It showed 0 bad blocks and 0 errors. Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: It can be.  I would see if the drive manufacturer has a utility as well, also as I stated in the answer, try a BIOS update.